# Figuring out Inductance

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, inductor, surface-mount, reverse-engineering

I am trying to figure out the Inductance used on this PCB. I know it's value but need to understand what type of inductor it is and other things so I can order it.

The code on it `100 M5D` yeilds no results. The value from schematic states it to be `10uH`.

Any help understanding the packaging/type/current etc. will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Look for Burns or Wurth power inductors. You can't be very wrong about it, just take anything on similar size (measure it)

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try looking for Burns or wurth on digikey

Comment: The code on it. It has to make some sort of sense right? @GregoryKornblum

Comment: Can be a date code, or a factory code. Don't bother.

Comment: Okay found a similar one from Wurth electronics. Hope it fits well on the footprint. Thank you for your help @GregoryKornblum. Answer the question so that I may mark it correct

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, Or Coilcraft or Eaton (Coiltronics) or Murata or Taiyo Yuden or .... That form factor is pretty common.

Comment: OK, now you got more credit.